# how to prioritize promise results?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, promise, state

I am working on a react app. I need to update the state with results from api request.Now the app functions such that I have to make api requests frequently. Therefore I set the state in then() once the results arrive. But some results take more time than others. So sometimes the result of the previous promise sets the state rather than the current. How do I prioritize the promises such that the latest request results sets the state. Or is there another way to get rid of the previous promises once I make a call to a new one?

```
this.state = {
      searchterm: '',
      isfocused: false,
      current: -1,
      noresults: false,
      // latest promise id
      reqseqid: 0,
      filteredList: []
    }


callingfunction(){
   let reqseqid = this.state.reqseqid + 1;
    this.setState({ 
      searchterm,
      filteredList: [],
      reqseqid
     });
    searchresults(searchterm, reqseqid)
      .then(res => {
        let { results, reqseqid } = res;
        console.log(reqseqid, this.state.reqseqid);
        if(reqseqid === this.state.reqseqid){
          if(res.length === 0){
            this.setState({ 
              current: -1,
              filteredList: [],
              noresults: true
             });
          }else{
            this.setState({ 
              current: -1,
              filteredList: results,
              noresults: false
            });
          }
        }

      });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I usually handle this is by having a instance property or similar variable that the asynchronous callback can check to see whether its results are still desired or the request is stale. For instance, in your constructor:

```
this.ajaxSequence = 0;
```

Then making your request:

```
const thisSequence = ++this.ajaxSequence;
doTheAjaxRequest()
    .then(result => {
        if (thisSequence == this.ajaxSequence) {
            // Use the result
        }
    })
    .catch(/*...probably check and ignore the error if this request was stale...*/);
```

It doesn't have to be a number. For instance:

```
this.currentRequestPromise = null;
```

then

```
const thisPromise = this.currentRequestPromise = doTheAjaxRequest()
    .then(result => {
        if (thisPromise == this.currentRequestPromise) {
            // Use the result
        }
    })
    .catch(/*...probably check here too...*/);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of doing this. One way I prefer is to have an object instance (a `requestSequence` of sorts) that keep track of requests received, along with an incrementing index value for each. When a request/promise returns, check if the index of that request index is >= the `largestIndex` you've already returned from `requestSequence`. If it is, then return that result, and increment the `largestIndex`. Otherwise, don't return that value.

The benefit of this approach is that the caller of this code can issue requests as fast as it wants, and `requestSequence` will ensure order. The caller won't have to be concerned with expiring requests or checking if the returned value matches the current input.

Comment: I did try something close to this. So the request sequence just keeps increasing. right?

Comment: Yep. It could be an integer that you increment, or perhaps a timestamp (unless your requests are coming more frequently than once per millisecond). Detail: `requestSequence` is an instance, and it stores an index within the instance (avoid global state).

Answer (score -1):

You should take a look at observables for your execution flow. What you are looking for is *flattening non concurrently a stream of promises* which can be done pretty easily with a library such as `xstream`:

```
const xs = require("xstream").default;
const promise$ = ... // create a stream of promises
return promise$.map(p => xs.fromPromise(p)).flatten();
```

Creating a stream of promises is easy, assuming you need to fetch periodically you can have

```
const promise$ = xs.periodic(500).map(() => makeApiCall());
```

I would strongly advise you look in this direction. Trying to handle directly promises within you component lifecycle is not straightforward and should probably be done in a Redux middleware (or other state management utilities). For instance it requires you track the state of your component being mounted/unmounted inside your promise's callbacks, otherwise you might do operations on unmounted components. This could also lead to memory leaks.

Comment: This would result in unnecessary component state updates for completions that are known to be stale, wouldn't it? Because you process the results in the order in which they were started, even if a later one completes before an earlier one so the earlier one's results are no longer desired.

Comment: not in what I posted. each time a new Promise arrives the previous one is dropped.

Comment: Okay, cool, thanks. I'll leave the comment in case anyone else wonders the same.

Comment: what you describe is stream concatenation where you wait for one to complete before processing the next. what I suggest is flattening which is different. non concurrently it drops the current stream when a new one comes up, concurrently it opens subscriptions to as many as possible as they come.