# How to give priority to a promise in JS or Node JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Yesterday, A interviewer asked me this question that "How do you give priority to a promise in JS/NodeJS ?".I was like you could use some thing like await or promise.resolve(), but he said that's not giving priority. Can anyone explain?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50879008/how-to-prioritize-promise-results

Comment: I looked at that question before posting my question it didn't answered my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, one possible way of doing this is using setImmediate and process.nextTick()
https://jinoantony.com/blog/setimmediate-vs-process-nexttick-in-nodejs/

> setImmediate() and process.nextTick() are two functions which allows us to control the order of execution of our code in the event loop. Both of these functions schedule our callback handlers in the event queue. But they are executed at different phases of the event loop.

Comment: @ShazilSattar how does this answer your question? You're asking how to give priority to a promise - using `setImmediate` or `nextTick` will just run the code you give it as soon as the run-to-completion cycle. How does it affect promises?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what he was getting at was that in a pool of promise, priority could be to solely resolve the first one in that pool, which you could do by using  Promise.race (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race)

Comment: But i still can't prioritze a promise it will just return the one which resolves faster\

Answer (score 0):

you can do promise chaining by this way, to make sure independent promises run in given order one by one:

```
function later(delay) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        setTimeout(resolve(delay), delay);
    });
}

//Promise 1:
let p1 = later(100)

//Promise 2:
let p2 = later(200)

//Promise 2:
let p3 = later(300)

p1.then(delay => (console.log(delay))).then(p2.then(delay => console.log(delay)).then(p3.then(delay => console.log(delay))));

//console:
//100
//200
//300
```